# How to display results according to the option selected in the dropdown list and checkbox in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display hotel results on the basis of the preferences selected by user. For example, if a user selects Pool from the preference and presses the submit key, a new window must be displayed containing the respective results.

In the same way, when user selects a place from the drop down list and presses "GO" button, it should display the specific web page but its not even responding.

Both of my buttons are not directing to the web pages I want. I am new in JavaScript and have tried my logic but it didn't work.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <div class="header">

<h1> Hello</h1>
</div> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function is_checked()
       {
        var Pool= document.getElementById('Pool').checked;
        var Gym= document.getElementById('Gym').checked;
        var Beach= document.getElementById('Beach').checked;
        if(Pool==false && Gym==false && Beach==false)
          {
             alert('Please check a category')
             return false;
          }

        else if(Pool==true && Gym==false && Beach==false && WiFi==false && Spa==false)
          {
              window.open("http://http://localhost/dubai rev/codeReviews.php");
              return true;
           }
       }

       function formaction(checkbox)
       {
         document.getElementById("myForm").action = checkbox.value;
        }




     function goToNewPage(dropdownlist)
 {
 var url = dropdownlist.options(dropdownlist.selectedIndex).value;
 if (url != "")
 {
 window.open(url);
 }
 }
      </script>
</head>
    <body background="trip.jpg" style="background-image:
    url(trip.jpg)">


<div class="menu">
<ul>

<li><a href="/signup">SIGN-UP</a></li>
<li><a href="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="#n">HOME</a></li>



</ul>
</div>

<ul>

<div>
<ul class="rig columns-3" id="content"align="left" >
    <li>

    <h1>STAY</h1>
 <form name="dropdown">
 <select name="list" >
 <option selected>Select a place</option>
 <option value="http://search.msn.com/">Dubai</option>
 <option value="http://www.google.com/">London</option>
 <option value="http://www.search.com/">Lahore</option>
 <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">New York</option>
 <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Canberra</option>
 </select>
 <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)">
</form>



    <br>
    <p2>Preferences</p2>
  <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" onsubmit="return is_checked()">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Pool" id="pool"> Pool <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Gym" checked="checked"> Gym <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Beach" id="Beach"> Beach <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="WiFi" id="WiFi" checked="checked"> WiFi <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" value="Spa" id="Spa" checked="checked"> Spa<br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </li>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: dropdownlist.options( dropdownlist.selectedIndex ).value; has to be dropdownlist.options[ dropdownlist.selectedIndex ].value;

Comment: Thanks alot! My dropdown list started working :) Thanks alot once again.

Comment: Can you please guide me regarding displaying the webpages according to the checkbox selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dropdownlist.options( dropdownlist.selectedIndex ).value;
```

has to be

```
dropdownlist.options[ dropdownlist.selectedIndex ].value;
```

For the webpages, you have overlloked quite a few things...assuming this is your actual code:

```
var Pool= document.getElementById('Pool').checked;
```

you're using 'Pool' when you've used 'pool' in HTML

```
...
else if(Pool==true && Gym==false && Beach==false && WiFi==false && Spa==false)
```

where have you initialized WiFi and Spa?

Also, no id for Gym checkbox.

And you do need to put %20 for the space in the URL.

Try all these.

Comment: I did initialize them and changed from "pool" in HTML to "Pool" but still it remains on the same page

Comment: Gym checkbox..no id there. Also initialise wifi and spa variables

Comment: That was a great help! Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: One last thing that i want to ask is that how can I display pool results according to the option selected in my drop down list.. for example, user selects a city in drop down list and then without pressing enter selects a preference checkbox suppose "Pool" so, only those hotels in that city should get displayed that have pools

Comment: How can I access dropdown options (Place selected) in my function isChecked()  for the above mentioned reason?

Comment: That depends on your data, you could use a global array that is changed on the select menu and checkbox's onchange events...and finally used in onsubmit.

Comment: using document.dropdown.list ...same as you used on the HTML page. Just use the same in code .. so you could use var dropdownlist = document.dropdown.list;  dropdownlist.options(dropdownlist.selectedIndex).value

Comment: What will be stored in the variable "dropdownlist"? The name of the city in a string or the index number of the option in the dropdown list?

Comment: i tried it in both ways like by first assuming var "dropdownlist" to be containing the name of the city and then byindex number but both failed.

Comment: if (dropdownlist=="Dubai" && Pool==true && .....)                                                                   if(dropdownlist=="1" && Pool==true && ....)

Answer (score 1):

http://http://localhost/dubai rev/codeReviews.php

You have a space here. An URL needs to be a constant string without space. Space if needed may be encoded via changing this character to "%20".

:)

Comment: I made it %20 and still its displaying me the same homepage again :(

Comment: @dev8080 I did correct that too but i didnt help :(

Comment: Try putting the options like this: dropdownlist.options[ dropdownlist.selectedIndex ].value

Comment: @dev8080 The dropdown list is now working. Thanks for your help! :) But still the checkbox selection isn't leading to the desired webpages :(

Comment: check my answer